# Morphism of surfaces contracting infnitely many curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

Let $S$, $S'$ be (smooth projective) algebraic surfaces over an algebraically closed field $k$ and let $f : S \to S'$ be a morphism between them. Suppose that $f(S) = S'$. Is it possible that $f$ contracts infinitely many curves to a point?

(note that this is false, if $f$ is a **birational** morphism)

**Motivation:** I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $S$ be a surface containing uncountably many smooth rational curves. Then $S$ is ruled.

The solution found on the internet (cf. http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~fsuzuk2/beauville_solutions.pdf, B (10), p. 7) considers two cases. In the first case we assume that $\dim \textrm{Alb}(S) \ge 1$. The map $\alpha : S \to \textrm{Alb}(S)$ contracts all the $\mathbb P^1$'s and thus the author concludes that $\dim \alpha(S) = 1$. Why?

Comment: If you have an abstract surface, lines do not make sense, unless you meant smooth rational curves/

Comment: Thanks, this is what I meant. I'm correcting it right now.

Comment: To solve your problem differently, consider the scheme $H:=\underline{Hom}(\mathbb{P}^1,S)$. Note that $H$ is a countable disjoint union of quasi-projective schemes $H^d :=\underline{Hom}^d(\mathbb{P}^1,S)$, where $d$ ranges over  all integers; the elements of $H^p$ correspond to maps of degree $d$. The assumption that $S$ contains *uncountably* many rational curves implies that there is an integer $d$ such that $H^d$ is positive-dimensional. Let $W$ be an irreducible component of this $H^d$. Then the "universal" evaluation-map $\mathbb{P}^1 \times W\to S$ shows that $S$ is uniruled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The basic result you need is the following. (A reference is Shafarevich, *Basic Algebraic Geometry 1*, I.6.3 Theorem 7 (ii).)

**Theorem :** Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a surjective morphism of quasiprojective varieties with $\operatorname{dim} X=n$ and $\operatorname{dim} Y=m$. Then there exists a nonempty open subset $U \subset Y$ such that $\operatorname{dim} f^{-1}(y) = n-m$ for all $y \in U$.

In your situation, the Theorem guarantees that there is a nonempty open subset $U \subset S'$ such that for any $u \in U$ the fibre $f^{-1}(u)$ has dimension 0. Let $Z = S' \setminus U$.

Now consider the closed subset $f^{-1}(Z) \subset S$. Note that all the curves contracted by $f$ are contained in this set.

Choose any irreducible component $W$ of this closed set. Since $Z$ is a proper subset of $S'$, the set $W$ is a proper subset of $S$.  By irreducibility of $S$, the set $W$ therefore has dimension at most 1, so it is an irreducible curve. Since $f^{-1}(Z)$ has finitely many irreducible components, there are finitely many contracted curves.